# How can I find this element by 'link_text'?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, automation, amazonsellercentral

I'm writing a code which can automate few process on Amazon Seller Central with Selenium + BS4.
I want to find an element by link text but it's not workin,,
[red rectangle is the part that I want to find by link text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVLbC.png)

I can find the element by class name or xpath but I can't find the same element with link text.
I need to find the element by link text cuz I'm going to use the account's name as a variable for my coworkers.
[the link text in the tag and the rectangle on the left side has same text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yotF8.png)

```
customer = "variable for my cowrkers"
browser.find_element_by_class_name('dropdown-button').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="partner-switcher"]/div/button').click()
time.sleep(7)

###### problem
elem = browser.find_elements_by_link_text(customer).click()
print(elem)
```

I need help :(

Comment: if I can't use 'link text' because it's not <a> tag.. Is there any way that I can find it by using variable like my code?

Answer (score 2):

You can try xpath

```
find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='picker-name' and text() = 'account text']")
```

So,

```
find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='picker-name' and text() = '" + customer + "']")
```